# Project Reactor: Enriching the result of a Flux with the result of a Mono

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I am working to introduce reactive programming to my company. I'm in the process of building a simple demo of an activity recommendation system to prove the performance benefits.

One of the challenges I have come up against is enriching the results in one stream with the results of another. I have a working example which is shown below but I am not sure if there are any issues with this approach. Could somebody take a look and provide any potential improvements.

```
    public Flux<Integer> getRecommendedActivities(Long userId, String location, Integer limit) {
        Flux<ActivityData> activities = activityDatabaseService.getByLocation(location);
        Mono<Map<String,BigInteger>> userCategoryScores = userScoresDatabaseService.get(userId);

        return activities
            .zipWith(userCategoryScores.cache().repeat(), this::scoreActivitiesBasedOnUserCategoryScores)
            .sort(compareActivityScoreStrength)
            .map(ScoredActivityData::getActivityId)
            .take(limit);
    }

    private ScoredActivityData scoreActivitiesBasedOnUserCategoryScores(ActivityData deal,Map<String, BigInteger> categoryScores){
        //This method combines the deal score and user category scores to come up with a final score
    }
```

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing inherently wrong with the code you have there. A few stylistic points which may or may not be helpful:

- The "norm" with reactive programming is to use a fluent style and inline everything throughout, rather than declare separate local variables at the top of your method and use those in the reactive chain.
- The `x.zipWith(y.cache().repeat())` pattern will work just fine, but I find it a bit ugly if it can be avoided (`zipWith()` implies two *real* `Flux` of data in my head, rather than a `Mono` that's been arbitrarily cached and repeated - so the behaviour is not necessarily as "stand out" obvious as it could be.) Instead, I prefer `y.flatMapMany(x)` - it makes it clearer that you're taking one value and applying a transformation to many values through a *real* `Flux`. So in your case, that might look something like:

  ```
  userScoresDatabaseService.get(userId)
          .flatMapMany(c -> activityDatabaseService.getByLocation(location)
                  .map(a -> scoreActivitiesBasedOnUserCategoryScores(a, c))
          )
          .sort() //etc.
  ```
- `Flux.sort()` should really be a "last resort" operation, especially since you cite performance benefits as a reason for exploring reactive. (Reading the entire data in from a database service, then sorting it, then only taking the first `n` values screams inefficiency - you'd be much better sorting and limiting the values in the data layer.) Bear in mind `Flux.sort()` will *have* to wait for the entire source `Flux` to finish before sorting & returning the values, storing every value in memory as it goes, so doing so loses many benefits of the `Flux` in the first place. It also makes your reactive chain shorter & simpler, since it doesn't need to worry about sorting and limiting.
- Nit: Some of your method names & variable names appear to be quite long. I'd shorten them if possible - I find this makes things much easier to read in the context of a reactive chain.

With the above points, your entire `getRecommendedActivities()` could read something like:

```
scoresDb.get(userId)
        .flatMapMany(c -> activityDb.getByLocation(location, limit, comparator)
                .map(a -> score(a, c).getActivityId())
        )
```

...which to me at least, reads much shorter & simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the detail was really useful! Decided to follow this pattern but going further and doing more in the data layer to simplify application logic!